# Display form input value as part of a new page url

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to display user entered value in form A to be part of the url of page B. For example:

Form A:

```
<form method="post" action="display_annotation_for_pdbid.php" target="_parent">
<fonttdresult><b>Search Database by PDB ID:</b><br/></fonttdresult>
<input type="text" name="pdbid" id="pdbid" placeholder="Enter a PDB ID" style="width: 
106px;">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

So instead of displaying the new page url as display_annotation_for_pdbid, I want it to display something like 'display_annotation?StructureID:1y26' when the user enters 1y26 in form A. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You can use `GET` method, then variables will automatically be placed in your url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use GET method iin your form to post data , variables will automaticlly be placed in URL

Comment: Just what I wanted. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Create another file `display_annotation_for_pdbid.php` which will contain code to redirect to required url. Try below code

display_annotation_for_pdbid.php

```
<?php
$pdbid = $_POST['pdbid'];
header("Location : display_annotation.php?StructureID=".$pdbid);
?>
```